# Trying to restore Google Chrome User Data

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to restore Google Chrome User Data, but when I open Chrome - after pasting the backup files - I get this message.

> Profile error occurred. Something went wrong when opening your profile. Some features may be unavailable.

I got the backup folder with ShadowExplorer. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, try deleting the file "web data" in :

> C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData/Default

And if it doesn't work then also "Local State" File in:

> C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData

If you can't see the folder or the files, they may be marked as hidden.
Take backups before deleting.

Comment: I tried, but I get the same message.

Comment: You can use less-strong method of restoring the profiles data, by restoring only the important parts, like bookmarks.

Comment: What I need is some files that are stored in the browser's internal memory. They were saved by CalmlyWriter - it's an online writing app. I cleared the browsing data and I didn't realise that they would be deleted as well. I've tried to find the specific files, but I couldn't find anything readable to copy-paste.

Comment: Try [ChromeCacheView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html).